# ArraList java não retorna dados

Tags: java, arraylist

Minha duvida consiste no seguinte problema.

Estou construindo uma aplicação (fins didáticos). Nesta tem um classe Contact que recebe uma String com nome, uma String com o telefone, além do construtor inicializar a data e hora da criação do objeto.
Uma classe Schedule que manipula a instancia contatos como adicionar em uma ArrayList os contatos, desde que o nome não seja exista ou o telefone.

Tenho um método que recebe uma String é deveria retornar todas as ocorrências que iniciam String dentro da coleção. Exemplo:

tenho os objetos: joão silva, joãozinho, joãozão - o método recebe joão. Neste caso o método retornaria todas as ocorrências com joão.

Bom pensei, percorro pela ArrayList verificando se o campo nome bate com as palavra e adiciono a uma Array local e retorno ela. utilizo o método startsWith() para verificar. Entretanto, não está retornando nada embora, os contatos foram adicionados. Consultando a internet não achei nada que ajude-me. 
Alguém poderia clarear dando-em novos pontos de vista para melhorar meu raciocínio?

Abaixo o código da classe agenda que recebe os objetos contatos.

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Responsável por armazenar os contatos.
 * 
 * @author (Vinicius Cavalcanti) 
 * @version (26.05.2016)
 */

public class Schedule
{
// Campos.
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;

/**
 * Construtor:
 * Recebe instancia um lista de contatos.
 * @param contact: recebe um objeto do tipo Contact.
 */
public Schedule()
{
    contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
}

/**
 * Método que insere um contato na agenda.
 * @param contact: instancia um objeto Contact.
 * impede que outro contato com o mesmo nome seja inserido ou;
 * se o telefone está vinculado a outro contato.
 */
public void insertContact(Contact contactNew)
{
    //Para o caso da lista estiver vazia.
    if (contacts.isEmpty())
      contacts.add(contactNew);

    else
    {
        String phoneNew;
        String nameNew;

        phoneNew = contactNew.getPhone();
        nameNew = contactNew.getName();

        //Condição para adicionar o contato
        if(searchPhone(phoneNew) == null && searchName(nameNew) == false)
            contacts.add(contactNew);
        else
        {
            //caso o telefone já exista.
            if(searchPhone(phoneNew) != null)
                System.out.println("telefone " + phoneNew + " está vinculado a outro contato");

            //caso o nome já exista.
            if (searchName(nameNew) == true)
                System.out.println("Contato " + nameNew + " já existe");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Método que faz uma busca dos contatos adicionados.
 * @param name: é o parâmetro da busca.
 */
public ArrayList<Contact> searchEarly(String name)
{
    ArrayList<Contact> search;
    search = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    Iterator<Contact> it = contacts.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Contact contact = it.next();

        if(contact.getName().startsWith(name))
            search.add(contact);
    }

    return search;
}

/**
 * Método que faz uma busca nos contatos adicionados baseado no telefone.
 * retornar para qual o telefone está vinculado.
 * @param phone: telefone a qual deseja consultar.
 */
public Contact searchPhone(String phone)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < contacts.size(); index++)
    {
        if (contacts.get(index).getPhone().equals(phone))
          return contacts.get(index);
    }

    return null;
}

public void imprime()
{
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    if (contacts.isEmpty())
      System.out.println("Não existe contatos a serem exibidos");
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Nome: " + contacts.get(i).getName() + " Telefone: " + contacts.get(i).getPhone() 
                                    + " criando em: " + contacts.get(i).getDate());
}

/**
 * método que retonar se o nome já existe na ArrayList contacts ou não
 */
private boolean searchName(String searchName)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < contacts.size(); index++)
    {
        if ( contacts.get(index).getName().equals(searchName) )
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Código da classe contato:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * Instancia o objeto contato.
 * 
 * @author (Vinicius Cavalcanti) 
 * @version (26.05.2016)
 */
public class Contact
{
// Campos.
private String name;
private String phone;
private Date dateHour;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;

/**
 * Construtor:
 * * @param name: instancia o atributo nome.
 * * @param phone: instancia o atritubo telefone.
 * Seta a data e hora que o objeto foi criado.
 */
public Contact(String name, String phone)
{
    setName(name);
    setPhone(phone);
    this.dateHour = new Date();
    this.sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}

/**
 * Método setter que altera o nome.
 * @param name: recebe o nome com variável do tipo String.
 */
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
/**
 * Método setter que altera o telefone.
 * @param phone: recebe o telefone com a variável do tipo String.
 */
public void setPhone(String phone)
{
    this.phone = phone;
}

/**
 * Método getter que retonar o nome instanciado.
 */
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

/**
 * Método getter que retonar o telefone instanciado.
 */
public String getPhone()
{
    return this.phone;
}

/**
 * Método getter que retonar a data e hora da criação do objeto.
 * No tipo String com o formato dia/mês/ano 00:00:00
 */
public String getDate()
{
    return sdf.format(this.dateHour);
}

/**
 * Método exibe as informações do objeto.
 * Nome, telefone e data de criação.
 */
public void imprime()
{
    System.out.print("Nome: " + this.name + " \nTelefone: " + this.phone + " \nCraindo em: " + getDate());
}

public String toString()
{
    String text = "";

    return this.name + " - " + this.phone + " - " + getDate(); 
}
}
```

agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente este código em seu metodo searchEarly:

```
public ArrayList<Contact> searchEarly(String name)
{
    ArrayList<Contact> search;
    search = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)
    {
        Contact c = (Contact)contacts.get(i);

        if(c.getName().startsWith(name))
            search.add(contact);
    }

    return search;
}
```

Comment: pergunta o objeto contact do método .add() não foi instanciado quem você está se referindo a variável c?

Comment: Marcus compilei aqui seu código sem fazer nenhuma alteração e deu certo. Você está adicionando os objetos **Contacts** em seu método **insertContact** da classe **Schedule**? Quando você executa o método **imprimir** aparece a lista de todos os contatos? Outra ponto, o método **searchEarly** diferencia letra maiúsculas de minusculas (Case Sensitive).

Comment: isso o método insertContact() é responsável por adicionar os contatos desde que passe nas condições (nome e telefone diferente dos da lista). Sim o método imprimir está normal, no terminal ele imprime toda a lista certinha, não ele não diferencia (a String passada tem que ser igual ao contato armazenado)